# c2hs not getting installed / registered correctly

Tags: haskell, ffi, c2hs

When I run `cabal install c2hs`, it seems to finish correctly, but doesn't register the package. The package seems as if it's not even installed: it doesn't show up in `ghc-pkg list`, and rerunning `cabal install c2hs` goes through the same install procedure, instead of saying "All the requested packages are already installed".

I'd much appreciate any help getting this up and running. I'm using the prebuilt GHC 7.4.1 binary.

- cabal install output: http://pastebin.com/CRUii8mm
- imports are defunct: http://pastebin.com/r0aypxRA

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As vivian says, `c2hs` is a preprocessor executable, and thus isn't registered with `ghc-pkg`.  Make sure that `$HOME/.cabal/bin` is in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C2HS module has been removed from newer versions of `c2hs`, since sometime prior to c2hs-0.15.  If you check out the c2hs source tree, you could find it by going back through the revisions.  Or some other libraries include it.  There's more information in this [trac ticket](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/c2hs-37-Export-C2HS-hs-module-from-library-part-of-the-c2hs-package-td3410835.html).  C2hs is moving towards making the functions in C2HS.hs completely unnecessary, although they aren't quite there yet (floating-point formats in particular need to be manually marshalled).

Answer (score 2):

I believe `c2hs` is an executable, not a library.  The cabal install output that you provided shows that the execeutable is placed in your private `.cabal/bin` directory.

Comment: How do I get the library `C2HS` installed then?

Comment: Just add `$HOME/.cabal/bin` to your `$PATH`